# White blur around image when using CSS3 blur filter?

Tags: css, filter, blur

Today I though I'd redesign my website and approach it from a different way. Instead of focusing on typography I though I'd just add a big image and little text. I simply done:

```
html {
    background: url(../img/background.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;

    filter: blur(10px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
    -moz-filter: blur(10px);
    -o-filter: blur(10px);
    -ms-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

...however when I see it in the browser (Chrome Version 26.0.1386.0 dev, running on Ubuntu 12.10), the image IS blurred but a faded white frame is also present. [Here is a screenshot of how this problem looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygvhr.png).

Is there any way to get around this? I had a look at [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224320/defined-edges-with-css3-filter-blur) but couldn't get it to work (partly because that example uses a `<img>` tag, not just a `<html>` one). That white frame just doesn't look good aesthetically. And no, the image doesn't have a white frame (it's simply a screenshot of my desktop, with couple of windows open, so no white frame present). Any ideas why this happens?

Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Try to set a background-color to your html. There may be a problem if you only use an image with a size, which is exactly the size of the viewport.

Comment: update. if I set you CSS to this page, I get a black border. The Black seems to come from the body-element. Try a transparent background on the body or the color of your image.

Comment: I don't think I seem to understand. I've set `background-color: #481124;` to the `html` tag but no change. What do you mean by "a transparent background on the body or the color of [my] image"? Also, the text is getting blurred as well (I noticed after I posted this).

Comment: Set a background color on the body element.

Answer (score 18):

If it's a possibility for you, a good workaround that I found is to make the image larger than the containing `<div>`, and also to clip the edges with an `overflow: hidden`.

In your case, because it's the whole `<html>` tag, I'd put the image in a `<div>` with the following CSS:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
transform: scale(1.02); // or whatever scale amount removes the border
```

This always works for me.