# Remove dark border around filter blur css

Tags: css

I'm having a problem and I cannot find any solution for this after a lot of searching.

I am using css filter: blur on a div but it is creating dark borders almost like a vignette around the div

How can I remove this?

[White blur around image when using CSS3 blur filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547064/white-blur-around-image-when-using-css3-blur-filter)

I am looking for a solution that doesn't include increasing the scale of the div like above

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
}

div {

-webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    -moz-filter: blur(3px);
    -o-filter: blur(3px);
    -ms-filter: blur(3px);
    filter: blur(3px);
    
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    object-fit: contain;
    border:none;
    
    }
    
    img {
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<body>

<div>
  <img src="https://resize.hswstatic.com/w_907/gif/tesla-cat.jpg" />
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried 'border:none' property to the div?

Comment: It's because your background color is black, which contrasts with the image which is light. Try setting the background color to white.

Comment: In theory yes you are correct, but I want to apply this across a range of situations where changing background colour isn't an option

Answer (score 1):

**A Solution:** It's a normal act of `css` blur on a element when you used a dark background color, in this case you used black background, so when you use `blur` this happen! for avoid this you should do a trick, use `transform: scale` on your image and make the parent `overflow: hidden` with certain `width` and `height`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
}

#pic img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
  -moz-filter: blur(3px);
  -o-filter: blur(3px);
  -ms-filter: blur(3px);
  filter: blur(3px);
  object-fit: contain;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

#pic {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="pic">
    <img src="https://resize.hswstatic.com/w_907/gif/tesla-cat.jpg" />
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of blurring the div, blur the img and scale the img to 1.1

This way doesn't make any soft "borders"

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
}

div {    
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    object-fit: contain;
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    img {
      -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
      -moz-filter: blur(3px);
      -o-filter: blur(3px);
      -ms-filter: blur(3px);
      filter: blur(3px);
      width: 100%;
      transform: scale(1.1)
    }
```

```html
<body>

<div>
  <img src="https://resize.hswstatic.com/w_907/gif/tesla-cat.jpg" />
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

To **`body`** that has a black (`#000`) background merges into the image. To change this, you can give the `<div>` that contains the image a white (`#fff`) background.

Note that in that case, **white** merges into the edges of the image, giving a whitish border, which may or may not be acceptable to you.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
}

div {
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  object-fit: contain;
  border: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
}

img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
  -moz-filter: blur(3px);
  -o-filter: blur(3px);
  -ms-filter: blur(3px);
  filter: blur(3px);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://resize.hswstatic.com/w_907/gif/tesla-cat.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with a parent container, slightly bigger image size and negative margin. The red border is just for illustration purposes and can be removed.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
}

.blur_img {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    object-fit: contain;
    overflow: hidden;
}
    
.blur_img img {
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
  -moz-filter: blur(3px);
  -o-filter: blur(3px);
  -ms-filter: blur(3px);
  filter: blur(3px);
  width: calc(100% + 12px);
  height: calc(100% + 12px);
  margin: -6px;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div>
  <div class="blur_img">
    <img src="https://resize.hswstatic.com/w_907/gif/tesla-cat.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```