# Cutting off the nasty edge of a circular blurred image

Tags: html, css

There's a few posts about this for cutting off the edges of a square image, however none for an image that takes the shape of a cirlce.

Unfortunately the solutions expressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224320/defined-edges-with-css3-filter-blur?rq=1) do not work, because it chops off the circle.

Here's a JSFiddle trying to use the solution above:  http://jsfiddle.net/3hg7ry9k/

CSS:

```
.fix {
     margin: -5px -10px;
}

.avatar {
    width: 128px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

**Basically, I'm trying to have a blurred circle image with crisp borders.**

Comment: what about overlaying an image on top of it with a circle cut out in it?

Comment: @codedude - Distorts the image even further, and causes the colors to become extremely dark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Should Set the blur effect to the img. and set the border-radius to the container:

http://jsfiddle.net/t1e1s5hb/

**HTML**

```
<div class="avatar">
    <img class="fix" src="http://pickaface.net/avatar/Opi51c7dccf270e0.png" width="150">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fix {
    margin: -5px -10px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}

.avatar {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This cuts off parts of the image when any additional scaling CSS is added, could you please provide a solution? JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y0jnc9tb/3/

Comment: Here's a screen-shot showing borders of my issue, as-well. (In this event the image is being cut off at the bottom) http://gyazo.com/f02614945293cf44cdb708e554779cfb

Comment: You Should Add The Scaling To The Container

Comment: The cut offs are because your margins. margin should be `-BlurRadius` from left and top. and your size must be bigger twice `Width + (2*BlurRadius)`

Answer (score 2):

It's not very compatible at this point but it is the future:

```css
img {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(50% at center);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://pickaface.net/avatar/Opi51c7dccf270e0.png"/>
```

(works on Chrome 43)

Comment: I'm sure this answer will help people in 2 or 3 years time when browsers catch up, unfortunately I have to support all agent browsers dating back to Android 2.3 and the iPhone3gs

Comment: A simple modern solution with >97% [support](https://caniuse.com/css-clip-path) (prefixed) across browsers as of Sept 2021.