# How to hide the apparent inset box shadow on background image when using filter blur

Tags: css, filter, shadow, blur

I wondered if anyone has come across this problem I'm having and might be able to point me in the right direction...

I have an image slider and each `li` within it contains the following:

```
    <li class="web">
        <div class="cd-full-width square">                  
            <h1 class="slider">Something interesting here</h1>
            <h2 class="letter">Something not as interesting here</h2>
            <a href="/website-design.htm" class="cd-btn button">More</a>
        </div> 
        <div class="bg">&nbsp;</div>
    </li>
```

Each `<div class="bg">` has a background image and I'm applying `filter: blur(5px);` to the div.

The blur works fine but I now seem to have an inset box-shadow around that div which I don't want.

[Example of box shadow here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfsTI.jpg)

I've tried to hide the shadow with by including `box-shadow` or `-webkit-drop-shadow` set to 0 / none. This doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas welcome!
Thank you :-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224320/defined-edges-with-css3-filter-blur

Comment: Thanks Paul for the related question. My problem was not a box-shadow but indeed the blurred edges.