# CSS - Remove background faded edges

Tags: css, blur

So im getting this issue where the picture is fading on the edges. The reason they fade on the edges is because of the filter blur. *(i need the blur filter)*
Any suggestions how i get rid of the fade or is it another way to do the blur effect in css, or do i have to do it in photoshop?

```css
.bg-img{
 background: url("http://hdwallpaperfun.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Snow-Mountain-Wallpaper-High-Definition.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
 background-size: cover;
 display: block;
 filter: blur(5px);
 -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="framside.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="bg-img"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224320/defined-edges-with-css3-filter-blur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also offset top, right, bottom, left with negative %. And then add the offset as % to the width and height. This, of course, assuming you are not too concerned with cropping the image slightly.

e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/mwzddfs6/

```
<div class="content"></div>

.content {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.content:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  left: -1%;
  right: -1%;
  top: -1%;
  bottom: -1%;
  z-index: -1;

  display: block;
  background-image: url(http://hdwallpaperfun.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Snow-Mountain-Wallpaper-High-Definition.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 102%;
  height: 102%;

  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}
```

ps: I also prefer to use content:before, to keep the code cleaner. personal preference, is all.

Answer (score 1):

You could stack a non-blurred version behind the blurred version:

```css
.bg-img-solid{
 background: url("http://hdwallpaperfun.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Snow-Mountain-Wallpaper-High-Definition.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
 background-size: cover;
 display: block;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0
}

.bg-img{
 background: url("http://hdwallpaperfun.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Snow-Mountain-Wallpaper-High-Definition.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
 background-size: cover;
 display: block;
 filter: blur(5px);
 -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="framside.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="bg-img-solid"><div class="bg-img"></div></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I merely duplicated and then removed the blur from the parent div.

Comment: Ye i thought about this, but it gotta be a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I simply fixed this issue by setting a negative Margin, this allowed me the image to grow in size and remove the blurred lines around the background image.

```
.blurred-bg-img {
margin: -5px;
position: relative;
background-image: url(assets/background.JPG);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top right;
background-size: cover;
padding: 350px;
filter: blur(2px);
```

}