Why are the edages of the screen not bluring with this css
I get when I use this css to blur the background image and add a radial-gradient to it, I don't want to blur the elements inside it:


body {
  background: radial-gradient( 50% 50% at 50% 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75) 100%), url("https://letsenhance.io/static/8f5e523ee6b2479e26ecc91b9c25261e/1015f/MainAfter.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin:0px;
}

body::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: inherit;
  filter: blur(8px);
  z-index: -1;
}
<body></body>


here is the link for the code pen
the edges of the screen don't blur/they are transparent (look at images:
image of the background with a camileon,
image of the background without a background image)
I know that the blur couses the issue, becouse when i remove it, the edges look fine.
I have tried to increase the width of the ::before of the body/ the body itself, add a div with the z-index of -2 and add a color to it.

For starters, you did not eliminate the 8px default margin body gets from the user agent stylesheet. If it still doesn't look like you want after that - then maybe you need to modify your gradient.

@C3roe removed the margin, still looks off

@C3roe and without the filter: blur(8px) the edges look fine

This is happening because of the Gaussian blur effect, here is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12224347/13970434

Perhaps I'm missing the point of this question, but have you considered applying min-height: 100vh to the body?

@André Yes, that fixed it, thx you so much
